# Call Access Macro from a SSIS package

Tags: ms-access, ssis, vba, ssis-2012

I want to execute access Macro from my SSIS package. Please help on how to proceed.AM using windows 8, Access 2013 and SSIS 2013

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the script component and run your vba code from there.